# Questions on using Lagrange Multipliers to find the closest point and the farthest point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I was looking for the solutions for these two problems:

1. Find the point on the plane $x+2y+3z= 13$ closest to the point(1,1,1).
2. Find the point on the sphere $x^2+y^2 +z^2 = 4$ farthest from the point(1,-1,1).

The solutions appear to use the same process using Lagrange multiplies. I.e. Find the gradient, of $f$ and $g$. Use the equation $\Delta f=\lambda \Delta g$ and solve for $\lambda$. Plug back in to find values of $x,y,z$ . Then evaluate $f$ at that point.

So does it make any difference finding the closest point or the farthest point?

Comment: Just a small remark: in the way to use Lagrange multipliers we solve for $(\lambda;x,y,z)$. And for the question, yes you're right. Just apply Lagrange with the restriction $d^{2}((a,b,c),(x,y,z))$, where $d$ denote the distance.

Comment: It's just like finding a max or a min, both would have had $f'=0$ and the only way to distinguish would have been to plug in to the function and find out which one is biggest.